# Сортировать числа от 1 до 10 через Sort

Tags: c#, winforms, строки, datagridview

Если кто знает как, прошу, помогите написать такой код сортировки по столбцу dataGridView, чтобы все адекватно было с двузначными числами. То есть значения в ячейке всегда в формате string и при сортировке он не может воспринять 10 как "десять", он воспринимает как "один и ноль". 
Пытался переводить ячейку в числовой формат через Convert, TryParse, Parse и tipeoff, но все безрезультатно. Неужели в C# подобное действие настолько сложное? 
Вот как сейчас выглядит сортировка:

```
void SortDataViewByColumn(DataGridView dataGridView, string nameColumn) // Подпрограмма сортировки по интересу
    {
        dataGridView.Sort(dataGridView.Columns[nameColumn], ListSortDirection.Descending);
    }
```

И ее вызов при нажатии на кнопку

```
 private void сортироватьЧастныеТаблицыToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SortDataViewByColumn(dataGridView2, "dataGridViewTextBoxColumn8");
        SortDataViewByColumn(dataGridView3, "dataGridViewTextBoxColumn2");
        SortDataViewByColumn(dataGridView4, "dataGridViewTextBoxColumn4");
        SortDataViewByColumn(dataGridView5, "dataGridViewTextBoxColumn10");
        SortDataViewByColumn(dataGridView6, "dataGridViewTextBoxColumn6");
    }
```

Прошу, помогите пожалуйста, у меня уже опустились руки - моих знаний языка абсолютно недостаточно для этого.

Comment: Ответ смотри здесь: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7572685/sort-string-items-in-a-datatable-as-int-using-c-sharp Мне больше последний вариант понравился: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13661830/5345074 Если в поле будут букавы, то будет ошибка конвертации.

Comment: судя по формату обработчика события click это WinForms, а почему в метках нет?

Answer (score 1):

С `DataGridView` можно работать в ручную, но это крайне неудобно. Воспользуйтесь свойством `DataSource` для привязки отображаемых данных к `DataGridView`, а сами данные разместите в отдельной коллекции и сортируйте ее как вам нравится по событиям от `DataGridView` или других элементов формы. Коллекция с данными может быть любой, но есть некоторые нюансы в поведении `DataGridView` при работе с разными коллекциями. Для простого отображения достаточно `List<YourDataItems>`, если нужна возможность без лишних затрат добавлять строки, то лучше использовать `BindingList<<YourDataItems>`. Ну и всегда остается вариант сделать полноформатный databinding, но это уже зависит от задачи.